# How to increase the notification time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have tried using the notification property of priority to increase the notification time but failed to do so. Please advise.

Following is the sample code.

```
chrome.notifications.create(
  "testing",
  {
    type: "basic",
    icon: "icon.png",
    title: "Test",
    message: "Hellow Word!"
  },
  function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      chrome.notifications.update("testing", {priority: 1}, function(){});
    }, 5000);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome 50 you can now use `requireInteraction` which i found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#property-NotificationOptions-requireInteraction).

Indicates that the notification should remain visible on screen until the user activates or dismisses the notification.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible I can clear the notification in a minute later if no action from the user after setting the requireInteraction = true?

Comment: Yeah. Else you can try to create a function that will trigger an Interaction and to be triggered in setTimeout function.

Comment: Note: **this is sadly not portable to Firefox**

Answer (score -1):

you need to set the timings in Testing section where the function is getting called.